# differences between tizen and Limo

Tags: linux, tizen, meego, limo

I was just wondering if Tizen and LiMo are same things.
Both are supported by samsung, but tizen is new version of meego and LiMo has been there since 2006.

Is samsung merging these platforms and if yes, how does that  work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The development for [Limo](http://www.limofoundation.org/) is targeted at using C/C++ SDK. But [Tizen](https://www.tizen.org/developers) is targeted at using HTML5 for creating apps.

See also [LiMo & Tizen FAQs](http://www.limofoundation.org/en/limo-a-tizen-faqs.html):

**What makes Tizen different from other mobile platforms?**
Tizen is a new open-source web-centric platform which supports advanced web applications, such as HTML5 and WAC. Tizen meets the mobile industry's desire for a unified mobile Linux platform built on moarket-tested technologies that is openly governed and adheres to open source principles. As Tizen will establish a third and truly independent mobile ecosystem we believe that it will attract more operators, service providers, vendors and developers.

**How does Tizen relate to MeeGo and LiMo?**
Tizen builds upon best practices and technologies from MeeGo and LiMo to deliver a complete cross-device open source software platform and will result in broader, stronger ecosystem support from leading service providers and OEMs. Intel will be working with partners to help them transistion from MeeGo to Tizen. In order to enable successful transition, sustainng engineering support will continue for MeeGo v1.1 and v1.2 releases into 2012. Intel will fold its ongoing MeeGo development efforts into the new Tizen project.

**What are the key differences between MeeGo, LiMo and Tizen?**
The key differences are Tizen's comprehensive, standards-based HTML5 application solution, broader industry support and a hardened mobile device stack.

Comment: does this mean there will be no native API support for tizen?

Comment: @Yogi - There is a note about this in the [blog](https://www.tizen.org/blogs/dawnfoster/2011/welcome-tizen): ... For those who use native code in their applications, the Tizen SDK will include a native development kit. We will open the entire Tizen software stack, from the core OS up through the core applications and polished user interfaces.